# com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER vs Install Referrer Library

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, google-play-services

What the purpose to use the `Install Referrer Library` instead of the intent `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` ? What is the advantage/drawback of each method?